# Set font for each part of multipart shape in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking for a way to set the font for each part of a multipart shape, rather than having to repeat the font commands for each line.  Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{
  labeled node/.style={
    rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    rectangle split draw splits=false,
    rounded corners,
    very thick,
    draw=orange!50,
    rectangle split part fill={orange!50, none},
    align=left,
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[labeled node] {
    \sffamily\bfseries\boldmath
    node $v_1$
  \nodepart{two}
  \slshape
  Contents of\\
  \slshape
  node $v_1$.
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the example, I must manually set the bold font for the first part, and the slshape for each line of the second part, which would be annoying if I have to create tons of these multipart shapes in my document and want them all identically styled.

How can I adjust the definition of `labeled node/.style` so as to make this font setting automatic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do `\nodepart{two}`, a style called `every two part node` is defined, and added at the start of the `nodepart`. As such, you can define this style and it will be used for all `nodepart`s called `two`, and if you have `font=\slshape` in a style the font declaration doesn't have to be added for each line.

For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{
  labeled node/.style={
    rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    rectangle split draw splits=false,
    rounded corners,
    very thick,
    draw=orange!50,
    rectangle split part fill={orange!50, none},
    align=left,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\boldmath
  },
labeled file/.style={
    rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    rectangle split draw splits=false,
    rounded corners,
    very thick,
    draw=blue!50,
    rectangle split part fill={blue!50, none},
    align=left,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\boldmath
  },
every two node part/.style={font=\slshape},
every twofile node part/.style={font=\bfseries}
}
\let\pgfnodeparttwofilebox=\pgfnodeparttwobox
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[labeled node] {
    node $v_1$
  \nodepart{two}
  Contents of\\
  node $v_1$.
  };
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[labeled file] {
    node $v_2$
  \nodepart{twofile}
  That of\\
  node $v_2$.
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is good enough for what I wanted, though it only works for one style.  E.g., if I had `labeled node` and a `labeled file` or something, what if I wanted a different style for part two of the labeled file?

Comment: @user3188445 Well you would need to give a different name to the second part in of labeled file, e.g. `\nodepart{twofile}`, and set the `every twofile node part` style to whatever you'd prefer.

Comment: But when I say \nodepart{twofile}, it gives an error.  Do I have to define some new type of multipart shape for this to work?

Comment: Oh, I guess I just need to say: `\let\pgfnodeparttwofilebox=\pgfnodeparttwobox` - no, that compiles, but doesn't show the parttwo part.  So I'm still not sure how to make your suggestion work.

Comment: @user3188445 I honestly don't know why that throws an error ...

Comment: It doesn't throw an error if I create the box, but it also doesn't draw part two of the split shape, because now part two is called part twofile.

Comment: Okay, I guess I got it working with `\let\pgfnodeparttwofilebox=\pgfnodeparttwobox` after all.  Not sure what I was doing wrong before, but when I cut and pasted your answer and added that let it worked.  If I create a new box instead of using let, though, it does not work.

Comment: @user3188445 Indeed it does. I updated my answer as well.